# How to create variable which contains function with input that are variable

Tags: javascript, function

I want to create variable which contains a function with variable input.

I tried this but no success

```
var setup = function( isAjaxSuccess ) {
    return function( ajaxSuccess = isAjaxSuccess ){

       if( ajaxSuccess === true ){
           console.log("success");
       } else {
           console.log("error");
       }        

    };

};
```

Here we call setup( true ) or setup( false ) according to which function changes.
Here console.log is just for show. Here setup( true ) should return a function basically.

Comment: Where is `data` being provided?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? There's a lot of things which can go wrong. The variable syntax seems to be correct

Comment: can take data as console.log("success");

Comment: syntax error @Samuel

Comment: Line? Where is the Syntax error? That's still too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return a function that uses `ajaxSuccess`:

```js
var setup = function(ajaxSuccess) {
  return function() {
    if (ajaxSuccess === true) {
      console.log('success');
    } else {
      console.log('fail');
     }
  }
};

setup(true)();
setup(false)();
```

You could also make it more concise like so:

```js
const setup = ajaxSuccess => () => ajaxSuccess ? console.log("success") : console.log("fail");
setup(true)();
setup(false)();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run the `return` statement; just check the input inside the conditional:

```js
var setup = function(ajaxSuccess) {
  if (ajaxSuccess === true) {
    console.log('success');
  } else {
    console.log('fail');
  }

};

setup(true);
setup(false);
```

Comment: Here setup(true) will not return a function which is what i want for my usecase

Answer (score 0):

Because calling `setup(true)` returns a function, you will need to, in turn, call that function. Try:

```
var setup = function(isAjaxSuccess) {
    return function() {
        if (isAjaxSuccess === true ) {
            console.log("success");
        } else {
            console.log("error");
        }
    };
};

var result = setup(true);
result(); // will log "success" to the console
```